# ARM Assembly Encryption using register operators

Tags: assembly, encryption, stack, arm

I'm trying to learn ARM assembly for a college class. The assignment is to use SP or r13 to emulate a stack for the encryption of a message. We have to

1. Encrypt the message using EXclusive OR (XOR)
2. Decode the Message
3. Compare the original and decoded messages if they're the same then bully if not the it's back to the drawing board.

I get the basic concept of the jump table. The main issue is that if I use 'EOR r2, r2, r8' is there another way to use exclusive or?

```
    AREA        Encrypter,  CODE,       READONLY

SWI_Exit    EQU     &11     ;finish program

    ENTRY               ; mark the first instruction
main    
    MOV r0, #0
    BL  JumpTable
    MOV r0, #1
    BL  JumpTable
    SWI SWI_Exit    

MESSAGE DCD "Yesterday all my troubles seemed so far away. Now it looks as though they're here to stay."
KEY DCD &12345678

JumpTable   
    ADR r1, SubTable
    MOV r0, r0,LSL #2
    LDR pc, [r1, r0]

SubTable
    DCD Encrypt0
    DCD Decrypt1
    DCD Print2

Encrypt0
    LDR r8 , KEY
    ADR 7r13, MESSAGE
    LDMFD   r13!, {r2-r7}
    EOR r2, r2,  r8
    EOR r3, r3, r8
    EOR r4, r4,  r8
    EOR r5, r5,  r8
    STMFD   r13!, {r2-r7}   
    MOV pc, r14

Decrypt1
    MOV pc, r14

Print2
    MOV pc, r14
    END
```

Comment: This code doesn't even assemble, which makes it kind of hard to have any faith in the rest of the question. I tried rewriting the directives in GNU syntax (with the build errors fixed up) to run it a dumb instruction set simulator, and it seemed to all execute as expected, so presumably it's an issue related to your environment, which you've provided zero details of. Try single-stepping through with a debugger and watching exactly where it seems to go off the rails - my wild guess would be the `stmfd` instruction (hint: look closely at your AREA directive).

Comment: Nolan, please take some time to format your questions. Try to make it concise. Things like "I appreciate that you guys take a look at my question" are just fluff. We are looking at your question already if we see that sentence somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Also, using stack pointer (r13) for data pointer is not exactly good practice, and it was supposed to be used for 'emulating' a stack (?). (Why emulate stack using stack pointer?) Also, the code only seems to encrypt the first 16 characters. It's still not clear what the stack is supposed to be used for. Subroutine calls?

Comment: I scrapped using r13 and that solved a lot of my problems. I'm still not exactly sure what my teacher was saying about emulating a stack using r13, but I did finish this and get it to run properly thank you for your help.